# kendo grid dynamic does not contain a definition for MinResizableWidth

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, resize, kendo-grid

Am using kendo dynamic grid .Displaying multiple dynamic grids in my MVC View .

For first grid am able to resize columns . But from second column am unable to resize columns . when i tried to resize it is throwing "**minResizableWidth' of undefined or null reference**"  in kendo.min.js file .

In my research about minResizableWidth in Kendo Doc .
The pixel screen width below which the user will not be able to resize the column via the UI.

and

Bug: Column Resize Handle not showing on dynamic Grid Columns

The problems are the hidden columns. If you have a hidden column in the grid, you can't resize all other columns after the hidden column. That is a very nasty bug, so please Kendo-UI team make a fix for it.

unable to find any solution for this script issue minResizableWidth' of undefined or null reference .

Hope for the best

Comment: I don't think this 'question' belongs on SO. You can report any bugs you have found through [Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/support/feedback).